# How to merge video and audio files without loosing original caracteristics

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have video.mp4 only file, and audio.m4a file.
I need to merge them both, and I need the output to be the same video without creating new resolution or modifing caracteristics.

OS: windows 10

Thank you.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @harrymc windows

Comment: Do you already have ffmpeg installed and have used it before?

Comment: Please do a little research before asking a question on Stack Exchange sites; this topic has been covered in a few questions here before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use command like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.m4a -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

this will ensure no changes are made in codecs, compression and so on